# Convergent series $\iff$ absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}},\#)$, where $\#$ is the counting measure.

It is easy to show that for $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ we have $\int_{\mathbb{N}}f d\#=\sum_nf(n)$.

Now, suppose $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f \in L^1$ if and only if $\int_{\mathbb{N}}f^+ d\#$ and $\int_{\mathbb{N}}f^- d\#$ are finite. So, if $f\in L^1$ we can write $\int_{\mathbb{N}}f d\#=\sum_nf^+(n)-\sum_nf^-(n)=\sum_nf(n)$, for the properties of convergent series.

This, combined with $f \in L^1 \iff |f| \in L^1$, yields that convergence is equivalent to absolute convergence, for series.

Can you help me spot the mistake?

Comment: the representation of Lesbeque integral always requires the finiteness of the absolute integral. So there is no mistake here. It is just you forgot the previous fact. Hope this help.

Comment: Consider $f(n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$... why should your argument work?

Comment: @FormulaWriter That's why it doesn't work, I'm not saying it does, but the contrary

Comment: There is no big deal. It depends on what you define to be a convergent series. One might define $\sum u_n$ to be convergent if the numerical sequence $\left(\sum_{k=0}^n u_k\right)$ is convergent (there is no measure theory here, just metric topology in $\mathbb{R}$), while other can define convergence to be Lebesgue-integrable, that is, absolutely convergent, which is not a metric statement.

Comment: The error is in the statement "It is easy to show $\dots\ \int_{\mathbb N}f\,d\# = \sum_n f(n)$." It's not easy to show that, because it's false. In the case of a conditionally convergent series, the right side of the claimed equation is defined but the left side isn't.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, OP is working with non-negative function there, so the result is true. Everything OP said is true.

Comment: @SangchulLee Indeed, as the values of $f$ are assumed to be nonnegative, then the assertions in the question are true, though the third paragraph (about $f^+, f^-$) and the fourth (about $|f|$) become rather pointless.  The conclusion "convergence is equivalent to absolute convergence" is as you said, also true for nonnegative $f$. The only actual mistake in the question is at the very end, asking to "spot the mistake".

Comment: @AndreasBlass I agree. Indeed, all the answers and comments (including yours) align with the point that OP's argument is correct line-by-line but the conclusion is not related to the "ordinary" convergence of infinite series.

Comment: @SangchulLee I've edited my question, I'm working with arbitrary functions after the beginning.

Comment: Note that, using the measure-theoretic language, the ordinary convergence of series corresponds to the improper integral: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{[N]}f\,\mathrm{d}\#,$$ where $[N]=\{1,2,\dots,N\}$. This is not directly covered by $L^p$-theory.

Comment: So you guys really consider that the convergence to infinity is also a part of $L^1$ ?  Really?
@warm_fish: So your question now is ?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen, I am not sure exactly which part you are concerned about, but if it is that part "... for $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ we have $\int_{\mathbb{N}}f\,\mathrm{d}\#=\sum_{n}f(n)$", then this is not related to $L^1$-theory.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen My question was "what mistake did I make?", since there are convergent series that don't converge absolutely. I just wanted to precise that I was working with possibly negative $f$, after the first two lines.

Comment: $f\in L^1$ iff $|f|\in L^1$ iff $\sum_nf(n)$ converges absolutely. And in this case, $\int f\,d\#=\sum_nf(n)$. In contrast, if $f\,d\#=\sum_nf(n)$ converges conditionally, then $f\notin L^1$, so $\int f\,d\#$ isn't defined (and in particular is not $f\,d\#=\sum_nf(n)$).  This is essentially what @SangchulLee said earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "**This**, combined with $f \in L^1 \iff |f| \in L^1$, **yields that** convergence is equivalent to absolute convergence, for series." is false.

If $\sum_n f(n)$ converges and $\sum_n |f(n)|=+\infty$, then you have proved nothing for $f$, since it does not satisfy the hypoteses of the properties you have proved (in fact in this case $f$ is not in $L^1(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}},\#)$).

According to measure therory, $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f d\#$ is defined for nonnegative $f$ first and it equals $\sum f(n)$. Then, the definition is extended for some functions $f$ assuming also negative values: in this case $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f d\#$ is defined as $\sum_nf^+(n)-\sum_nf^-(n)$ if at least one of the terms $\sum_nf^+(n), \sum_nf^-(n)$ is finite. If $\sum f(n)$ is convergent but not absolutely convergent, then $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f d\#$ is undefined. Have a look at Adam's answer.

Comment: Oh I see. The problem is that a convergent series $\sum_n f(n)$ need not to be $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f d\#$, right?

Comment: When does the series representation hold, exactly? If $f \in L^1$ it holds, for instance, as I wrote before.

Comment: @warm_fish You need at least one among $\sum_nf^+(n), \sum_nf^-(n)$ to be finite. I extended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is defined to be in $L^1$ if $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f^+ \,d\#$ and $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f^- \,d\#$ are both finite.  **If** this happens, then $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f \,d\# = \sum_{n} f(n)$ is defined to be $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f^+ \,d\#$ - $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f^- \,d\#$.  So $f \in L^1$ is the same as saying $(f(n))_{n}$ is absolutely convergent.  Conditionally convergent sequences are those for which $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f^+ \,d\#$ and $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f^- \,d\#$ are both infinite, but somehow they "collude" to make $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f^+ \,d\#$ - $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f^- \,d\#$ finite (when you consider this integral in the sense of summing from $n=1$ to $\infty$).  These sequences aren't considered to be part of $L^1$.